# Adding a row by clicking on the Add button in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-community

I am working on a Windows Forms application and I have a grid view which lists all the users found in a database. Database looks like this:

**table Users**

**table Privileges**

Now, every user can have only one privilege, like Admin, or User etc, but I keep this info in a separate table and have a foreign key constraint defined in such way that an end user can't insert a user with a wrong privilege but rather, just from those which are found in Privileges table.

By the way, I am using Entity Framework and I have created my Model object using Database First method. But this likely doesn't affect on a question/answer because logic of what I am going to ask is probably the same, no matter how do you manipulate with data from database.

So, right now, I have two binding sources, one is called `userBidningSource`, and other is `privilegesBindingSource`. User model has a navigation property to Privileges and vice-versa (this is generated by EF). Now I have dragged a user data source from Data Sources menu, to my form, and wrote some code (in my form load) like this:

```
try{
   context.user.Load();
   this.userBindingSource.DataSource = context.user.Local.ToBindingList();

}catch(Exception ex){
    Debug.Write(ex);
}
```

Now this works (I probably forgot to add all code, but until now everyhing works) and I get a list of all users with all the columns from a Users table.

Now because it is unsafe and doesn't make sense to leave to the end user to choose/guess what privilege_id field should be entered, I made a combobox on a grid view for that column.

So I added something like this in my code:

```
 context.privileges.Load();
       this.privilegesBindingSource.DataSource = context.user.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Also I have set data source of this column in a designer (right click on a grid view , then Edit Columns) to the privileges datasource.

Now all drop downs are filled as it should.

**The Problem**

Finally, the problem... Right now, I am trying to add a new row. So if I click on + icon of a grid view, I get an error which says :

> "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid. To replace this default
>   dialog please handle the DataError event."

So the question is, how to add a row with a current setup ? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the event DataError by going to the dataGridView properties and leave the function body empty/blank.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror(v=vs.110).aspx.  Refer to this document. It might help 

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [DisplayMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [ValueMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) properties so when a new row is added, it will use that knowledge to populate the combobox. You may also want to add a method so when a new row is requested, it will call your handler so you can specify what the default values for the new row should be. You can add an event handler to the `DefaultValuesNeeded` event and specify defaults like this for example:

```
private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender,
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["Region"].Value = "WA";
    e.Row.Cells["City"].Value = "Redmond";
    e.Row.Cells["PostalCode"].Value = "98052-6399";
    e.Row.Cells["Country"].Value = "USA";
    e.Row.Cells["CustomerID"].Value = NewCustomerId();
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the response! I will try it tonight as soon as I get my hands on a computer...

Comment: I just checked. I actually DisplayMember (privilege_name) and ValueMember set (privilege_id which is the primary key). Now I don't really know if I want default values. I want all those empty. Also, I got the same error when I populated row with default values. It must be something obvious in my setup... ?

Comment: Try setting the default for the combo box in the default even handler and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I am still getting DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.  I did this in even handler :    `e.Row.Cells["privilegesidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value =  aDefaultValue;

Comment: If that solved it that means there was some error, the error which brought you to ask the question, and now adding that `DataError` basically swallows that error. So the error is not gone, it is simply ignored and it may surface in another format. You should actually see what the exact error is as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I just implemented DataError method and I got two errors. One says, Error with formatting, Display, and another says : Preferred size ...